# Weird Text showing up in SharePoint

Tags: 2010, form, internet-explorer, chrome

so I have been trying to trouble shoot this Bug for some time but have been unsuccessful in identifying a solution. When filling out or viewing forms in Internet Explorer, odd text appears like so:

[image: Odd Text]

However this problem doesn't appear in Chrome.
It isn't just the editing from a pop-up or links, as when I simply go to view a form in a non-pop up page I can see the text issues as well:
[image: IE Viewing]

But doesn't have that issue here in chrome:[image: Chrome Viewing]

So if anyone has some solutions for me to solve this problem in IE then I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: What are your language settings in IE (Internet Option -> Languages -> Language preferences) - Those strings are looking like missing localizations

Comment: US English
https://pasteboard.co/Ht58rPI.png

Answer (score 0):

Are your user's workstations or browsers set to anything other than English? It looks like SharePoint is looking for language resource files that are not there.

As for the browser differences, they have different defaults for detecting the user's language preferences.

Comment: No, all of these workstations and browsers should be set to US English.

https://pasteboard.co/Ht58rPI.png